# Matlab OOP: Create a handle class that (inherits from) is also a double?

Tags: matlab, oop, operator-overloading

I would like to create a class that inherits (and acts) as a double but is also a handle. For example:

```
a     = myHandleDoubleClass();   % Instance of my handle double.
a.val = 1;                       % Set value of a to 1.
b     = a                        % Assign b to the value of a
                                 % but, b is a double, not object
>> b

b = 
    1
```

now if I change the value of a (for example set `a.val = 2`) then `b` should also change so that it has the same value (or more correctly both a and b are in effect pointers to the same value).

Is this possible in Matlab somehow?

EDIT: To further clarify, these handle objects should later on be used as normal doubles and need to act as such for access operations (for example `b=a`, `b=a(ind)` etc. without having to explicitly access the value property (its ok to use the property field to set the value, `a.val = 1`). The purpose is to have an double object that is used in many places (other objects, including patches) and you only have to change the value in one place (and all other references update automatically due to the handle property).

EXAMPLE:

One application would be something like this, crate a patch with vertices of my double class

```
f = [1 2 3];
v = myDoubles();

patch( 'faces', f, 'vertices', v )

v.values = updateValues();
drawnow
```

so whenever I change the values at one point, the patch also updates its values without having to explicitly go in and change the vertices field.

Comment: Why not have a Handle class which has a double parameter?

Comment: Does my most recent update cover the case that you need?

Comment: I've been doing more research, and it looks like multiple inheritance is possible in Matlab. I need some more time to work out the details of your example, but here's the documentation that leads me to believe your desired behavior may be possible: [Subclassing built in class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/subclassing-matlab-built-in-classes.html) and [Inheriting from multiple classes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-subclasses--syntax-and-techniques.html#bruug7f).

Comment: Thanks for your time one this, don't worry about it though. I tired to make my own double class but 'patch' would not accept it as a numeric (even overloading isnumeric), so in the end I just overloaded patch instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Writing your own pointer class

If all you need is a pointer to a `double`, you can have the double be a parameter of your class. Here's a simple example based on code from [Using pointers in Matlab](http://www.matlabtips.com/how-to-point-at-in-matlab/)

First you define a class that inherits from the handle class, which is Matlab's pointer class. The class properties will store your double.

```
classdef HandleObject < handle
   properties
      Object=0; % This will be your double
   end

   methods
      function obj=HandleObject(receivedObject) %This is the constructor
         obj.Object=receivedObject;
      end
   end
end
```

Then you can write your example above as,

```
a = HandleObject(1); %The constructor passes the 1 to the Object property
b = a; 

display(b.Object); % Should print 1
```

To access the value of `a` and `b`, you need to use `a.Object` or `b.Object`.

To be clear, you can actually use `HandleObject` to construct a pointer to any Matlab object type, not just doubles. If you call, `h = HandleObject("Hello World")`, you will store a String in `h.Object`.

## Using pointers to other Matlab classes

If you use this method with a Matlab object like `patch` you run the risk that Matlab copies the values in `HandleObject.Object` rather than using the pointer.

For example,

```
v_array = [0 0;1 0;1 1;0 1]; % x and y vertex coordinates
f_array = [1 2 3 4]; % vertices to connect to make square
v = HandleObject(v_array); % make a vertex pointer
f = HandleObject(f_array); % make a face pointer
patch( 'Faces', f.Object, 'Vertices', v.Object, 'FaceColor','red');

v.Object = [1 .5; 1 1; .5 1]; % Let's use the pointer to change the vertices
f.Object = [1 2 3]; % and faces to a triangle
drawnow; % But we don't see any change in the figure
```

The reason we don't see a change is because `patch` copied the values to its own variable rather than storing a pointer. As far as I know, there is no way to force `patch` to use our pointers instead of copying the value, but there is an alternative: to use a pointer to the `patch` object to change the values.

```
v_array = [0 0;1 0;1 1;0 1];
f_array = [1 2 3 4];
p = patch('Faces',f_array,'Vertices',v_array,'FaceColor','red'); %The patch method optionally returns a handle index
h = handle(p); % Get the handle

% Now I have a pointer to my patch object which I can use to change any property
h.faces = [1 2 3]; % Such as the number of faces
h.vertices = [1 .5; 1 1; .5 1]; % And the location of vertices
h.facecolor = 'green'; % Even the color
drawnow
```

Many Matlab methods, such as `patch` optionally return pointers to the objects that they create, allowing you to change the properties on the fly. Other methods will provide you with handles to useful classes. I often use the `gca` method for example, to change the properties of my plot's axes.

Comment: Yes, this is one approach I've thought of but ideally I would like to be able to work with it just the same as with doubles, that is assign values as a = 2, get values as a(ind) where a also can be an array of doubles. and b should mirror the changes in a.

Comment: @BautaSteen `a.Object` and `b.Object` will behave exactly as you describe. You'll just have to type an extra 7 characters.

Comment: I don't think it'll work in my intended application though. The purpose of this was to have "pointers" to doubles that work as normal doubles to be used in among other things the vertex field in patch objects so that I only would have to update one place when the points change.

Comment: If you could add an example of how you are going to use them, it might help me understand why you can't use what I am proposing. What I'm trying to explain is that `a` and `b` **are** pointers  to the same class instance which contains a double `Object`. Changes to `a.Object` also change `b.Object`. You will only have to update one of them to see the changes in the other one. `Handle` is Matlab's way of saying pointer.